# How to import values from Laravel into react.js

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel

How do I import a variable value from PHP Laravel into my React.js frontend.
Is that even possible to begin with.

Thank you from Zambia.

the variable from PHP

```
{{$category->category_name}}
```

and the div from react.js

```
<div>{category_name}</div>
```

*I have no where to begin from, so ye sorry I couldn't provide any work that I have done*

Comment: There are plenty of ways to get variables from the backend to the frontend. I really recommend you do some tutorials to **understand the basics of PHP and Javascript** before learning a MVC Framework like `Laravel` or using `reactjs`. **Its always better to understand the raw matter** before using frameworks and complex libs.

Comment: The reason is, if you start Using such third party bundles early on while learning, you will mich likeley bareley ever be able to use the plain JS/PHP and always rely on those libs for certain tasks. It also helps a lot to understand how everything plays together ("in vanilla") later on, to build big applications. I know its not so much fun because you can not simply do fancy things in a few hours, but believe me after almost 20 years of developing, you will benefit. I write this because your question tells me you haven't understand the role of PHP and Javascript in webdev. at all. No offense

Comment: @Jonathan Thank you so much, am learning so hence the question. I so hope to learn from the best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to pass values from html to react through as innerHTML in your html element. In order to accomplish this you have to render each html component separately through `ReactDOM.render`

Setup your html element with the inner Content, Render the component in `ReactDOM.render` and pass that data through inside the element. Grab the value in your React block like you would any `props.children` passed through

```js
/* pass through as props.children */

function App(props){
return <div>Child: {props.children}</div>
}

const application = document.getElementById('application');
ReactDOM.render(<App>{application.innerHTML}</App>, application );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<!-- pass through as props.children -->
<div id="application">From HTML</div>
```

Comment: thanks so much @androidoverlord i will try this.

Comment: Awesome! If it works for you @Epigie please mark it as answered;)